# Bind a collection type to ViewModel property

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, reactive-swift

I have an array of items (each corresponds to a cell data) and I want to create an array of cell ViewModels.

When I try to map the item to MutablePropery, I get `Binary operator '<~' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MutableProperty<[CellViewModel]>' and '[CellViewModel]'`

How should I change the below code in order to get reactive stream?

```
class ListViewModel {
var poiData = MutableProperty([CellViewModel]())

init(poiWrapper: PoiWrapper) {
    self.poiData <~ poiWrapper.poiList.map({ (poiItem)  in
        return CellViewModel(poi: poiItem)
    })
  }
}
```

**My Intention is to create a structure like the one below:** From [MVVM + ReactiveCocoa](https://blog.joanzapata.com/mvvm-reactivecocoa-5/). The code I shared is ViewModel of my ViewController, where I tried to create cell ViewModels as soon as initiate my Parent ViewModel.
[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of doing so? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If the property is a map of some other signal then it should just be a regular property and not a mutable one and no binding is necessary (ie map returns a property):

```
class ListViewModel {
    let poiData = Property<[CellViewModel]>

    init(poiWrapper: PoiWrapper) {
        poiData = poiWrapper.poiList.map({ (poiItem)  in
            return CellViewModel(poi: poiItem)
        })
    }
}
```